# Structure factor of crystals (X-ray crystallography)

Tags: geometry, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

How can one prove that the degree of each node in a distance graph must be at least four in order to obtain a unique solution to an exact distance geometry problem with sparse distance data?

The example in the Wikipedia article has three degrees for each node, which is less than four, but I am guessing the information derived in this case is not the same as what I am trying to prove; i.e. it is not a unique solution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry).

I am pretty confused, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest possible case where you get ambiguity is that of 5 nodes. In the complete graph on these nodes every node has degree four. If we remove a single edge we get ambiguity (in general): it contains a complete graph on 4 nodes (the edges of a tetrahedron) and the fifth node is connected to three of the others, but not the fourth. If we reflect the node in the plane of those three nodes, the distances in the graph don't change, but those in the arrangement do.